# How can I find out when a system of linear equations have a non-trivial solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I have two linear equations:

$(a-1)x + 2y = 0$

$2x + (a-1)y = 0$

How can I figure out for what values they have non-trivial solutions whereas $x$ and $y$ aren't 0?

Comment: do you know what a determinant is?

Comment: I know how to calculate the determinant, yes. Even though I can't quite fathom what it's good for. As far as I've understood, a augmented matrix can also be used to solve this problem, but I don't understand how.

Comment: In that case, I'd first recommend that you pick a specific value of $a$ like $6$ and understand how to use both augmented matrices and determinants to answer the question for that $a$.

Answer (score 0):

For $\ a=1$ you have:
$$\begin{cases}x=0 \\ y=0 \end{cases}$$
For $\ a≠1$
$$\begin{cases}(a-1)x+2y=0 \\ 2x+(a-1)y=0 \end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}(a-1)x+2y=0 \\ x=\frac{1-a}{2}y \end{cases}\implies \begin{cases}-\frac{(a-1)^2}{2}y+2y=0 \\ x=\frac{1-a}{2}y\end{cases}$$
$$\implies \begin{cases}y \left(2-\frac{(a-1)^2}{2}\right)=0 \\ x=\frac{1-a}{2}y\end{cases}$$
now if $\ (a-1)^2=4 \implies a=3$, you have  $\ 0=0$ in the first equation, so there are $\infty^1$
solutions depending on a parameter $\ t$
$$\begin{cases}y=t \\ x=\frac{1-a}{2}t\end{cases}, \forall{t\in{\Re}}$$
In all the other cases, so for $\ a≠3$, the solution is $\begin{cases}x=0 \\ y=0 \end{cases}$

A much faster way to proceed was to compute the determinant of the coefficient matrix:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
a-1&2\\
2&a-1
\end{pmatrix}$$ $$det \ M = det \begin{pmatrix}
a-1&2\\
2&a-1
\end{pmatrix}=(a-1)^2-4$$
putting $\ det \ M=0$, you get the $\ a=3$ value, for which there are infinite solutions.